# DataTrigger not changing template in ItemContainerStyle for Listbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, itemcontainerstyle

my idea is to change appearance of ListboxItem when MouseOver or Button is clicked etc.

```
<ListBox Name="listbox"
         Height="250"
         Grid.Row="4"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center">
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Template"
                  Value="{StaticResource control_mouseover}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Template"
                  Value="{StaticResource control_not_mouseover}" />
        </Trigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=grid.Artykuły, Path=IsPressed}"
                     Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Template"
                  Value="{StaticResource control_mouseover}" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Only for events IsMouseOver it works but DataTrigger does not seem to work 
Do you happen to know why?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="control_not_mouseover"
                 TargetType="ListBoxItem">
  <Border BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource not_mouseover}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="control_mouseover"
                 TargetType="ListBoxItem">
  <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource mouseover}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
</ControlTemplate>
<StackPanel>
  <Grid Name="grid"
        Height="240">
    <Button  Name="Artykuły"
             Grid.Column="0"
             Content="{Binding Path=liczba_wpisow, Converter={StaticResource wpisy_converter}}" /> [...]
  </Grid>
  <Listbox... />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: what is grid.Artykuły? and where it is?

Comment: I updated. Grid and Listbox are both in StackPanel, take a look at the end of a question.

Comment: Sorry, DataTrigger is not working at all and this is the problem.

Comment: did you try with just `Binding="{Binding ElementName=Artykuły,` and not gird.Artykuly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a number of problems with your code. The first is that you don't need to add a `Trigger` for both `true` *and* `false` conditions. Instead, you should do this:

```
<ListBox Name="listbox" Height="250" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource control_not_mouseover}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource control_mouseover}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=grid.Artykuły, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource control_mouseover}"/>
                </DataTrigger>                  
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

However, this should *not* cause an actual error.

The second problem is that the `ElementName` property show be set to the actual `name` of the relevant control and not to the type and name:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Artykuły, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource control_mouseover}"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

UPDATE >>>

To permanently apply your `Template` rather than just having it when the `Button` is pressed, just remove the `DataTrigger` and move the `Setter` out of the `Triggers` collection:

```
<ListBox Name="listbox" Height="250" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource control_not_mouseover}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource control_mouseover}"/>
                </Trigger>            
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Unfortunately, your `Setter` values clashed, so I had to swap them over to make it work this way, but I believe that you can re-arrange it as you see fit.

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought that if I want to get access to element of Grid I need to include in ElementName name of grid, but never mind. By the way, DataTrigger brings effect when it's pressed and effect disappears when it's not. What can I use instead DataTrigger to keep effects for good?

Comment: @michael I think you have to use an EventTrigger on `Button.Pressed` to do that. See http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/event-based-property-changes

Comment: But I need to set Template and I do not think it's reachable by EventTrigger.

Comment: I did the same but you deleted part connected with Button. When Mouse is Over Template is supposed to be changed, when Button is pressed template is supposed to be changed and both for good, that my concern.

Comment: Oh, I understand your problem now... I don't think that that can be achieved with XAML. You may need to add handlers for the `MouseEnter` and `Button.Click` events where you can change the `Template` property permanently.

Answer (score 1):

```
Binding="{Binding ElementName=grid.Artykuły

<Button  Name="Artykuły"
```

-> ElementName does not match your element's Name.

Should be :

```
Binding="{Binding ElementName=Artykuły
```