# XAML separate binding of ContainerStyle and ContentTemplate in ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listboxitem, itemcontainerstyle, contenttemplate

I tried this for a while now and searched in the web without success... Now I dare to ask on stackoverflow myself.

So, the aim is to separate the definitions of the `ItemContainerStyle` and the `ContentTemplate` of a `ListBoxItem`. I have defined the `ListBoxItemStyle` in a `ResourceDictionary` and two different `DataTemplates` in the `Window.Resources`.

I now like to set the style of the `ListBoxItem` according to the one defined in the `ResourceDictionary` and change the `DataTemplate` with a trigger (`IsMouseOver`).

My *(not working)* Code so fare looks like this:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="20,60,10,10"
         Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
         PreviewMouseMove="DragMove_PreviewMouseMove"
         PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Drag_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
         Style="{StaticResource DefaultListBoxStyle}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource DefaultListBoxItemStyle}"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PersonsListBoxItemTemplate_default}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PersonsListBoxItemTemplate_infoButtons}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

where `DefaultListBoxStyle` is the style defined in the `ResourceDictionary` and `PersonsListBoxItemTemplate_default` & `PersonsListBoxItemTemplate_infoButtons` are the DataTemplates defined in the `Window.Resources`.

Now I get an error, that the style-object must not have an impact on the style-property of the object it belongs to.

I tried different ways, but without success... I also tried to define the style first and then change the template, but it does not work either.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve (you've only stated how as far as I understand). Is it different than this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296531/datatrigger-not-changing-template-in-itemcontainerstyle-for-listbox?rq=1 ?

Comment: So, the difference is, that I'd like to use a style defined in the ResourceDirectory which other ListBoxes use too. And with the trigger i'd like to only change the DataTemplate. The part which does not work is to set the Style... It should be somehow like in the code above. (Was this clearer...?)

Comment: Remove the <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource DefaultListBoxItemStyle}"/> and extend StyleTag to: <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultListBoxItemStyle}">

Comment: @Fabian Thx! I thought, it should be that easy! Could you write it as answer, such that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can't set Style Property in Style with Setter. For this you need to use BasedOn:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultListBoxItemStyle}">
    <Setter ... />
</Style>
```